Why does adding a number to a useState array make it non-iterable, but adding a string works?
I have a React component where I'm using the useState hook to manage an array. Initially, my state is defined like this:
const [rows, setRows] = useState([1]);
When I try to append a number to the array using a button click:
setRows([...rows, 1])
and iterate through the rows:
rows.map((row) => console.log(row)); 
I encounter an error:
TypeError: rows is not iterable.
However, if I append a string instead of a number, for example:
setRows([...rows, 'a'])

Do: console.log(typeof rows);'
console.log(Array.isArray(rows));
console.log(rows); after definition and right before map. If it have changed, it means you are modifying it somewhere else somehow. Strings are iterables (it iterates through the characters), numbers are not.

I can't replicate this issue. Its working for me. Can you share the code you are using.

In react ,when using usestate hook for managing arrays, you typically want to update the sate in an immutable way. This means you should create a new array that includes the existing elements along with the new element you want to add. The issue you are having with adding a number to usestate array making if 'non-iterable'.
Correct Way
When you want to add an element to an array in state, you should use spread operator(...).
Example
const [myArray,setMyArray] = useState([]);
//Adding a number
const addNumber = () => {
    setMyArray(prevArray=>[...prevArray,number]);
}

